# My y-axis ticks are way too close to each other

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

[image: Graph image]

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={f},
ylabel={},
axis lines=left,
xmin=0, xmax=210,
ymin=0, ymax=9000,
xtick={10,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,170,200},
ytick={327.8 , 631.0 , 1180.5 , 1775.7 , 2262.7 , 3115 , 3561.4 , 4156.6 , 6240 , 8323.3 , 8323.3 , 4156.6 , 2262.7 , 1552.5 , 1180.5 , 951.5 , 796.5 , 684.4 , 558.1 , 480.1},
legend pos=north west,
]

\addplot[
color=black,
mark=*
]
coordinates {
(10,327.8)(20,631.0)(40,1180.5)(60,1775.7)(80,2262.7)(100,3115)(120,3561.4)(140,4156.6)(170,6240)(200,8323.3)
};
\addplot[
color=black,
mark=*
]
coordinates {
(10,8323.3)(20,4156.6)(40,2262.7)(60,1552.5)(80,1180.5)(100,951.5)(120,796.5)(140,684.4)(170,558.1)(200,480.1)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome! Well, you are manually choosing your ticks. If they don't fit, they don't fit... if you just remove the `ytick` line the graph will be much better.(same for `xtick`, really).